# LibGDX - ImageButton - Setting Image With Background

Tags: android, libgdx

From my understanding, the `ImageButton` within `LibGDX` is a frame containing an image. Is it possible to set the background of the frame?

For example, I would like to use a Button background, and apply an Icon on top of that image.

### Current Code

Skin with the background:

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle": {
    "default": {
        "imageDown": "button-down", 
        "imageUp": "button-up"
    }
}
```

Creating the ImageButton:

```
// Getting imageButtonStyle with "default" style, as it just has the background.
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle imageButtonStyle = skin.get( "default", ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle.class );
ImageButton button = new ImageButton( imageButtonStyle );
// Set the image on the button to something.
```

### Background image.

[image: static background Button image]

### Background image with icon overlayed.

[image: static background Button image with heart icon]
[image: static background Button image with mail icon]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

The trick is using the 2 different Styles available. ImageButtonStyle to set the icon attributes, but since ImageButtonStyle extends ButtonStyle, the background attributes are set in ButtonStyle. Something like:

```
ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
style.up           = background;
style.down         = background;
style.checked      = background;
style.imageUp      = icon_up;
style.imageDown    = icon_down;
style.imageChecked = icon_checked;
style.unpressedOffsetY = -20; // to "not" center the icon
style.unpressedOffsetX = -30; // to "not" center the icon

ImageButton heartButton = new ImageButton(style);
ImageButton envelopeButton = new ImageButton(envelopeStyle);
```

Something like that (for me, backround, icon_* are Drawable). But that's the basics and worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement your own button class that extends ImageButton.
Then, if you overload the constructor, you can pass either Drawables or Textures for imageUp, imageDown and background to it:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.SpriteDrawable;

public class myButton extends ImageButton
{   
    public myButton(Texture texture_up, Texture texture_down, Texture background)
    {
        super(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(texture_up)),
              new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(texture_down)));

        this.setBackground(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(background));
    }
}
```

Now, you can use your own Button class and instantiate it as follows:

```
Texture textureUp   = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/image_up.png"));
Texture textureDown = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/image_down.png"));
Texture background  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/background.png"));
MyButton myButton   = new MyButton(textureUp, textureDown, background);
```

Maybe play around with it a little and you'll find out what else you can do with it. Just make sure that you have the images in the correct resolution. Background doesn't have to be an image.

Comment: Did you test this out? I tried this approach but it doesn't work correctly. The other, more highly upvoted, answer seems to be the way that works.

Answer (score 0):

A button by definition will have three states:

imageDown - When the mouse is clicked on the button

imageUp - When the mouse is released on the button

imageChecked - When the mouse is hovering on the button

In the scene2d api there isn't a way yet of manually setting the imageButton's background image but if you do want something like that its best to have an array of images and an index as to what image you want, and render using a sprite batch e.g:

```
Texture[] images;
int currentImage;
```

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from the LibGDX API. With a [Button](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html), it has Drawables for up, down and checked. But looking at [ImageButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html), it says "A button with a child Image to display an image." My understanding from this would mean that the ImageButton has an Image on top of the already 3 Drawable states. Is this not the case? If not, what does that mean?